# Is it acceptable to call setState in the callback to setState?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code;

```
handleBlur = event => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    }, () => {
        validateInput(this.state, name).then((errors) => {
            this.setState({
                errors: errors
            })
        })
    });
}
```

On the event firing, I set the username/password in the component state. In the callback, I validate that all fields meet my criteria, and return any errors that are encountered. I then run setState again to put these errors in state. My question is, is there a better way to do this? It doesn't seem practical at all to have setState inside a setState.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's for validation, I think you should using setState inside a callback because it will make the components render multiple times.

You can remove the callback by setting the `name` and `errors` into a single setState.

```
const validateInput = (state, inputName, inputValue) => {
  const errors = { ...state.errors };

  if (/* condition */) {
    errors[inputName] = /* error's value */;
  }

  return errors;
}

handleBlur = event => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;

    this.setState({
        [name]: value,
        errors: validateInput(this.state, name, value),
    });
}
```

I hope it helps you!

Comment: That works perfectly - The only concern I have is validateInput is an async function, so it's returning a promise - And it has to, because it has an API call. I think I'll deal with validation in ComponentDidUpdate, as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn’t set values in handleBlur, instead set values in handleChange and validate and set errors if any in your handleBlur event handler.
Still if you want you should set values and errors in a single setState instead of making two calls.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a good point. I didn't consider using both onChange and onBlur. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use componentDidUpdate for updating errors

```
handleBlur = event => {
  const name = event.target.name
  const value = event.target.value
  this.setState({ [name]: value })
}

componentDidUpdate  (prevProps, prevState)  {
  if (prevState[name] !== this.state[name])
   validateInput(this.state, name).then(errors => {
     this.setState({ errors: errors })
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, just move the validation out like this:

```
handleBlur = event => {
  const name = event.target.name;
  const value = event.target.value;
  this.setState({ [name]: value });
  validateInput(name, value)
    .then((errors) => this.setState({ errors }));
}
```

Comment: validateInput takes the current state, though. Since setState is sync, it might not give me the correct data unless it's the callback.